# Por que da codigo de error 500 este php para registrarse?

Tags: php, mysqli

estoy intentando usar esto para hacer un sistema de registro en mi pagina y lo que hace es que me da código de error 500 y/o no me inserta el registro con los datos.

```
<?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "oscpia_blog";
    $dbpass = "oscar27";
    $dbname = "oscpia_blog";
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["pass"];

    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO usuario (email_usuario, pass_usuario) VALUES('$_POST["email"]','$_POST["pass"]')", $con);

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email_usuario = '".$email."' and pass_usuario = '".$password."'");
    $nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($nr == 1) {
        echo '<script language="javascript">alert("¡Registrado con éxito!"); location.href="registrar.htm"</script>';
   } else if ($nr == 0) {
    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Hubo un error en su registro!"); location.href="registrar.htm"</script>';
   }

?>
```

Comment: Al parecer el problema radica en el juego de comillas en tu sentencia query que intentas insertar, en vez de esto:  VALUES('$_POST["email"]','$_POST["pass"]')     prueba esto: VALUES( '$email' , '$password' )

Comment: las dobles comillas de tu INSERT INTO... estan mezclandoe con las dobles comillas de tu $_POST["email"] y$_POST["pass"]

Comment: @Santiago Hola, sí, ahora ya no da el error 500 pero ahora el problema es que no inserta el registro en la base de datos. ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: En tu. sentencia : INSERT INTO usuario... estas colocando la variable : "$con"  como el segundo parametro encambio debe ser el primer parametro de la funcion: "mysqli_query" y por cierto tu variable de conexion es: "$conn" y vos has colocado "$con"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con :

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "oscpia_blog";
$dbpass = "oscar27";
$dbname = "oscpia_blog";
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["pass"];
$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO usuario (email_usuario, pass_usuario) VALUES('$email', '$password')", $con);
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email_usuario ='$email' and pass_usuario = '$password'");
$nr = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($nr == 1)
{
  echo '<script language="javascript">alert("¡Registrado con éxito!"); location.href="registrar.htm"</script>';
} else if ($nr == 0)
{
  echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Hubo un error en su registro!"); location.href="registrar.htm"</script>';
}
?>
```